# no menu bar when login with root at ubuntu 16.04

Tags: menu

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2A8X.png)

1. login use 'vivo' user
2. gedit a file, or other app, it show menu bar and everything is good
3. 'su -', login with root
4. open gedit or other app
5. cannot see menu bar, even put mouse on the top, only have 'close/min/max', after click max the button, slide bar will cover apart of the display window.

please help me.
Thx a lot